# Чем удобна конструкция $$переменная и когда ее следует использовать?

Tags: php

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $$key = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $base_connection);
}
```

Интересует именно вот этот момент - $$key.  Просмотрел документацию, но толком не понял. Чем удобна такая конструкция $$переменная и когда ее следует использовать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Документация - [переменные переменных](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php)**

В цикле создается переменная, имя которой есть ключ массива.

Пример:

```
$arr = array("name1"=>'test1',"name2"=>'test2',"name3"=>'test3');
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $$key = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $base_connection);
    // строка выше пропускает $value через mysql_real_escape_string
    // и присваивает полученное(экранированное) значение $value переменной с именем 
    // ключа массива (в Вашем примере массивом выступает массив $_POST);
    echo "$$key = '$value';";
}
```

В результате мы получим:

```
$name1 = 'test1';
$name2 = 'test2';
$name3 = 'test3';
```

**UPD:**

**Чем удобно?**

Это существенно упрощает работу с кодом(еще одна формулировка "создание переменных на лету"). Т.е. Вы динамически можете создавать различные переменные. Полный пример описан в документации.

**Когда не нужно использовать?**

1) Когда возможно перекрытие значений и Вы не проверяете создаваемую переменную. Самый простой пример, когда приходят массивы `$_POST` ил `$_GET` и Вы сразу же записываете значение переменной.

Пример:

```
$name1 = 'dima';
$arr = array("name1"=>'alexey');
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $$key = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $base_connection);
}
echo $name1;
//Выведет 'alexey', т.к. в цикле переменной `$name1` будет присвоено значение `alexey`
```

*Решение* - прежде, чем записывать значение, проверять имя переменной на валидность или существование.

2) Если не решена проблема двусмысленности. То есть, если вы напишете `$$a[1]`, обработчику необходимо знать, хотите ли вы использовать `$a[1]` в качестве переменной, либо вам нужна как переменная `$$a`, а затем ее индекс `[1]`.

*Решение* - использовать синтаксис для разрешения двусмысленности: `${$a[1]}` если Вы желаете использовать `$a[1]` в качестве переменной и `${$a}[1]` если Вам нужна переменная `$$a`, а затем ее индекс `[1]`.

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста когда её следует использовать и чем удобна. Автор просил)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавили, но в доках и так все хорошо написано.

Comment: Эт понятно. Просто тут тогда можно было каждому третьему просто ссылку на доки давать)))  Спасибо за подразвернутый ответ. Кому-то он будет более полезен.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский теперь просьба более понятна)